# Simple lyrics application

Tags: react.js, jsx

I am fairly new to React, but I have been reading a lot of the official documentation and trying to do things correctly.

**Background:**

I am building a simple lyrics application in ReactJS, it looks something like this:

[image]

The application is deployed [here](https://bejebeje.com) and the code is [open source](https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/Bejebeje.React).

**The bit to review**

The code for the search component is the `Search.jsx` file:

```
import React from "react";
import posed from "react-pose";
import "./Search.css";

const SearchButton = posed.div({
  active: {
    width: 600,
    borderRadius: 3
    // transition: { duration: 20000 }
  },
  inactive: {
    width: 68,
    borderRadius: 50
    // transition: { duration: 20000 }
  }
});

const SearchInput = posed.input({
  active: {
    width: 600,
    padding: 15
  },
  inactive: {
    width: 0,
    padding: 0
  }
});

class Search extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.searchInput = React.createRef();
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSearchButtonClick = this.handleSearchButtonClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      query: "",
      isActive: false
    };
  }

  handleSearchButtonClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      isActive: !this.state.isActive
    });
    this.searchInput.current.focus();
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    this.props.search(event.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    const { isActive } = this.state;
    return (
      <SearchButton
        className="search__wrap"
        pose={isActive ? "active" : "inactive"}
      >
        <form className="search__form">
          <SearchInput
            type="text"
            className="search__input"
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            ref={this.searchInput}
          />
          <button
            className="search__button"
            onClick={this.handleSearchButtonClick}
          >
            <i className="fal fa-search search__icon" />
          </button>
        </form>
      </SearchButton>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

Here is the top level `App.jsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Router } from "@reach/router";
import Authorisation from "./components/Authorisation/Authorisation";
import Artists from "./components/Artists/Artists";
import ArtistLyrics from "./components/ArtistLyrics/ArtistLyrics";
import Lyric from "./components/Lyric/Lyric";
import { API_CONSTANTS } from "./helpers/apiEndpoints";
import "./App.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.searchArtists = this.searchArtists.bind(this);
    this.handleSearchInput = this.handleSearchInput.bind(this);

    const artists = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("artists"));

    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      isLoading: false,
      artists: artists || [],
      searchTerm: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const artistFetchDate = localStorage.getItem("artistsFetchTimestamp");
    const date = artistFetchDate && new Date(parseInt(artistFetchDate, 10));
    const currentDate = Date.now();

    const dataAgeInMinutes = Math.round((currentDate - date) / (1000 * 60));

    const tooOld = dataAgeInMinutes >= 15;

    if (tooOld) {
      if (!this.state.isLoading) {
        this.fetchArtists();
      }
    } else {
      console.log(
        `Using data from local storage that is ${dataAgeInMinutes} minutes old.`
      );
    }
  }

  fetchArtists() {
    this.setState({
      artists: [],
      isLoaded: false,
      isLoading: true
    });

    fetch(API_CONSTANTS.artists)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        result => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            isLoading: false,
            artists: result
          });

          localStorage.setItem("artists", JSON.stringify(this.state.artists));
          localStorage.setItem("artistsFetchTimestamp", Date.now());
        },
        error => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            isLoading: false,
            error
          });
        }
      );
  }

  handleSearchInput(searchTerm) {
    if (searchTerm.length >= 3) {
      this.searchArtists(searchTerm);
    } else {
      this.fetchArtists();
    }
  }

  searchArtists(name) {
    this.setState({
      artists: [],
      isLoaded: false,
      isLoading: true
    });

    fetch(API_CONSTANTS.searchArtists(name))
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        result => {
          console.table(result);
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            isLoading: false,
            artists: result
          });
        },
        error => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            isLoading: false,
            error
          });
        }
      );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <Artists
            path="/"
            artists={this.state.artists}
            search={this.handleSearchInput}
          />
          <ArtistLyrics path="artists/:artistSlug/lyrics" />
          <Lyric path="artists/:artistSlug/lyrics/:lyricSlug" />
          <Authorisation path="/callback" />
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Although the search currently "works", it isn't ideal, on each key pressed it re-renders the list of artists and even when the actual search starts happening (when the user types 3 characters or more), it against re-renders on each key press.

A few concerns I have:

1. In terms of data flow and lifting state up, have I got that correct? My `searchTerm` is kept in the `App.jsx` component and so is my artist list. The artist list is passed to `Artists.jsx` component for rendering.
2. How can I stop unnecessary re-rendering?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can stop re-rendering. Just don't `.setState()` :)

I think what would are trying to achieve is the illusion of all the band data being on hand, when search is snappy.

UX-wise you have a choice to make:

- is search instantaneous, or
- is search an activity

#### Live search

- if you have the artist list, search in-memory, that's always best!
- if you must make a network call, maintain cache of responses:

  - either in-memory / localStorage cache, or
  - set response header and rely on browser to cache the responses
- when search input is changed:

  - if you have matches in cache, display them
  - if you don't, kick off async fetch, but don't change the screen
  - when you get the results, if input changed yet again, don't display
  - [maybe] after a timeout (input idle, NNNms passed, results not ready) show spinner
  - when you have matches in cache that match the input, display them

Here's a first, ugly pass at how I'd start prototyping this flow:

```
const [current, setCurrent] = useState("");
const [, refresh] = useState();
const [lastChangeTime, setLastChangeTime] = useState(0);
const [lastData, setLastData] = useState([]);

const search = async (what) => {
  global_cache[what] = await (await fetch(`${url}/?q=${what}`)).json();
  // FIXME ugly, consider observing cache
  refresh(Math.random());
};

const timeout = (ms) => new Promise(
  resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const kickSpinner = async () => {
  await timeout(500);
  refresh(Math.random());
}

const change = (e) => {
  setLastChangeTime(Date.now());
  setCurrent(e.target.value);
  search(e.target.value);
  kickSpinner();
};

// FIXME ugly, not functional, maybe redux?
const data = global_cache[current];

if (data) {
  // FIXME ugly, may loop, maybe useEffect?
  setLastData(data);
}

const spinner = (Date.now() - lastChangeTime) >= 500;

return (data?
          <BandList data={data}>:
          spinner?
            <Spinner/>:
            <BandList data={lastData}>);
```

#### Activity

- require user to hit Enter or click the search button
- gray out current screen or show "loading..." or a snipper
- show list of matches when you have them.